# Change value of the point-in-time in DynamoDB using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to enabled point-in-time recovery property for new table in the DynamoDB using java.

```
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, dynamoDBMapperConfig());
    CreateTableRequest tableRequest = mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(tableClass);
    tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput( new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));

    PointInTimeRecoverySpecification specification = new PointInTimeRecoverySpecification();
    specification.setPointInTimeRecoveryEnabled(true);

    UpdateContinuousBackupsRequest request = new UpdateContinuousBackupsRequest();
    request.setTableName(tableRequest.getTableName());
    request.setPointInTimeRecoverySpecification(specification);
    amazonDynamoDB.updateContinuousBackups(request).getContinuousBackupsDescription().getPointInTimeRecoveryDescription().setPointInTimeRecoveryStatus("ENABLED");
    CreateTableResult result = amazonDynamoDB.createTable(tableRequest);
```

But on UI side I see that point-in-time recovery is set to DISABLED.

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try making the create table request before you make the request to turn on continuous backups.

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'll make my comment into an answer so that it's clear for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The table must be created before you send the request to enable Continuous Backups.